# How to get rid of "git" from Android Studio Toolbar at the top? Screenshot attached

Tags: android-studio

[image]

How do I get rid of this Git icons from the top toolbar of Android studio? It's taking too much space and I don't really use it. I tried to get rid of it from the preferences but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Git.

[image]

Customize menus and Toolbars : select it.It will pop new dialog [image]

You can see minus '-' sig. you can manage this way

Edit

[image]

[image]

Comment: This removed the "Git" from Main-menu. I want to remove the Git and it's option from the toolbar which has options to "update project, commit and push" in colored icons, as you can see in the image I've attached.

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: I checked, my "MainToolBarSettings" is empty, so I can not expand it. It's just a folder/directory for me with nothing inside.

Comment: @Sahil : Which Android studio are you using ?

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.mallowigi (36.0), Dart (211.7798), io.flutter (64.0.2)


The one for M1 chip